# Is the song "Driver's License" anti-woman?

Tags: lyrics

"Driver's License" by Olivia Rodrigo is about a woman still insanely in love with her ex who has dumped her.

Should this be considered an anti-feminist song because it shows women weak towards men, and love itself?

Comment: Please, can you provide a solid reference that feminists hate this song? By "solid" I mean a link to an article from a reputable media, or a link to a feminist association website. Else, I'm afraid that this assertion is someone's abusive generalization, inferred from isolated comments on social networks, which would make your question groundless.

Comment: @xhienne Did I certainly say "Feminists hate this song" that you ask me to give a reference? I *asked* myself. please note the question mark.

Comment: When you write "Do Feminists hate this song because ...", the way that I understand your question is that you are postulating that feminists hate this song and you are asking us whether your explanation ("it shows women weak towards men and love itself") is correct. If I misunderstood your question, would you mind rephrasing it unambiguously? What are the premises and what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

Oxford Languages defines feminism as

> the advocacy of women's rights on the basis of the equality of the sexes.

These lyrics have nothing to do with rights, and could, for the most part, be equally well sung by a man about a woman (or by someone of any gender about someone of any gender) so they don't seem in conflict with feminism. I'm not getting why you're connecting her "weakness" with her gender, since the lyrics don't draw any such connection.

Quite a lot of songs about love --from whomever's perspective --deal with difficulties in getting over a lost lover. You seem to be laboring under the misconception that feminism is predicated upon denying common aspects of the human condition.

Comment: So, IOW, the question is more biased than the lyrics themselves ;-)